# Measurement of grinding wheel waviness

Tags: electronic-filters, grinding

I have done experiments on a grinding machine and have collected the data of grinding wheel profile (using a laser sensor).

The raw data consists of info on grinding wheel profile, waviness and 
roughness (because of abrasive grains). I would like to process the collected raw data. I want to filter out the high frequency and low frequency data. (I want to apply a simple band pass filter). One cycle data is about 200,000 data units and i have them in an excel file (csv data) and would like 
to perform digital filtering.

How do I filter out the waviness data separately and analyze, from this?

Comment: Are you looking for help doing filtering in Excel? or what exactly?

Comment: You asking how to do fourier tansform in excel?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the form of your data.

Comment: At the very least you'll have to define a cutoff between off-axis error (a disc rotating not about its center),  eccentricity or ellipse-ishness, and "waviness" which presumably is of higher order.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it's not clear if these measurements are made in the axial direction or the radial.

Comment: I read a recent thesis by a researcher in Canada all about analyzing grinding wheel topography with chromatic light sensors. It might not be as simple as you think. You should be able to access the thesis without paying here: http://dalspace.library.dal.ca/handle/10222/64674.

Comment: For a former employer, I used to make waviness, roughness and other surface measurments of mechanical seal faces, but I don't know what the OP is even asking.